# React native error while running a sample application on a device

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I tried to install the reactive native in windows 10, then I created a sample project and try to run it on a device but I am getting error and was unable to load to the device.
I tried most of all the areas mentioned in stack overflow, bot still unable to load the app to the device.
When I run that I got the message as

**

> > @ start C:\Users\Bodha PC - 1\Videos\rn\revi-proj
> >     expo start Starting project at C:\Users\Bodha PC - 1\Videos\rn\revi-proj Expo DevTools is running at
> >     http://localhost:19002 Opening DevTools in the browser... (press
> >     shift-d to disable) error Invalid regular expression:
> >     /(.*\__fixtures__\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\__tests__\.*)$/:
> >     Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more
> >     details. Metro Bundler process exited with code 1 Set EXPO_DEBUG=true
> >     in your env to view the stack trace. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
> >     errno 1 npm ERR! @ start: `expo start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
> >     npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> >     problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm
> >     ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> >     C:\Users\Bodha PC -
> >     1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-29T05_23_21_908Z-debug.log
> >     The log file content is 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose
> >     cli [ 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose
> >     cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
> >     1 verbose cli   'start' 1 verbose cli ] 2 info using npm@6.12.0 3 info
> >     using node@v13.0.1 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start',
> >     'poststart' ] 5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @ 6 info lifecycle @~start:
> >     @ 7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 8 verbose
> >     lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Program
> >     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Bodha
> >     PC -
> >     1\Videos\rn\revi-proj\node_modules.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;"C:\Program
> >     Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
> >     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program
> >     Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin";C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
> >     Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
> >     Management Engine
> >     Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
> >     Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
> >     Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
> >     (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
> >     Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
> >     Components\IPT;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program
> >     Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Python27;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program
> >     Files\nodejs\;c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program
> >     Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
> >     Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Bodha PC -
> >     1\AppData\Local\watchman;C:\Users\Bodha PC -
> >     1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Bodha PC -
> >     1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program
> >     Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.1\bin;C:\Users\Bodha
> >     PC - 1\AppData\Roaming\npm 9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD:
> >     C:\Users\Bodha PC - 1\Videos\rn\revi-proj 10 silly lifecycle @~start:
> >     Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ] 11 silly lifecycle @~start:
> >     Returned: code: 1  signal: null 12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to
> >     exec start script 13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start` 13
> >     verbose stack Exit status 1 13 verbose stack     at
> >     EventEmitter. (C:\Program
> >     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
> >     13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5) 13 verbose
> >     stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program
> >     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> >     13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5) 13 verbose
> >     stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16) 13 verbose
> >     stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> >     (internal/child_process.js:283:5) 14 verbose pkgid @ 15 verbose cwd
> >     C:\Users\Bodha PC - 1\Videos\rn\revi-proj 16 verbose Windows_NT
> >     10.0.18362 17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
> >     "start" 18 verbose node v13.0.1 19 verbose npm  v6.12.0 20 error code
> >     ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 1 22 error @ start: `expo start` 22 error
> >     Exit status 1 23 error Failed at the @ start script. 23 error This is
> >     probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> >     output above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

**

I tried most of all steps as told by others in stackoverflow, but still not working
The screen when I try it on a device is shown below,

So can any one help me with this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDKkP.png)

Comment: How you run your sample app, kindly share your commands that you use to run app.

Comment: now my app is working, the issue is with the node version, as I have installed the node 13 version, when i downgraded it to node 10 its working correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome, you are right node 13 is not stable yet and has issues.